# VS code CSS class selector not found with angular and bootstrap 5 beta

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 with angular and I add style and script to angular.json but the problem in VS Code it does not recognize the bootstrap classes.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Uninstall this extension named "HTML CSS Support" and then reload.
It worked for me, I hope it would work for you as well.

Comment: I just reloaded VS Code because the extension was updated automatically and just needed a reload.

Comment: Issue was still present after reload for me in an eleventy project that used a CSS framework from node_modules. I tried other answers that were given here but to no extent. I finally fixed it  by downgrading the 'HTML CSS Support' extention to v1.3.3

Comment: Yes, they have added css validations in version [1.5.0] , that might me in beta state...

Comment: I was getting the message "CSS class selector 'text-muted' not found". Excellent thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be an issue with the same 'HTML/CSS Support' extension mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65463006/14632909) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65474434/14632909). It looks like there have been 7 different releases for that extension in the last few days. v1.3.3 seems to be the latest working version of the extension.

Answer (score 6):

Reverted to v1.3.3 of 'HTML/CSS Support' extension until sorted 
Works on my machine

Answer (score 4):

Check if extension "HTML CSS Support" got auto-updated. If it did, then it will ask for reloading of VS Code. Do it. Had exactly same issue today.

### Update

That did not help.

Looks like the issue should have been solved with the next release of the extension, but still, some of the Problems are there. Check the github:
https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css/issues

In short, what you need to do is go to VS Code settings and switch from "User" to "Workspace". Then type "css settings" in settings search bar and open the exact same option under "Extensions". Click "CSS: Style Sheets", which will open settings.json for workspace and add your CSS files paths there. Hopefully it will solve all the Problems for you.

[image]

Comment: not working all the time, just turn the validation off in your vscode settings.json. Add this at the end of the file `"css.validation": { "id": false, "class": false }`

Comment: It's bad that we have to do that thought. The extension should explore all css/scss file for your workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Install this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css

Then in your .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
  "css.styleSheets": [
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ]
}
```

Restart vscode. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using newer version of HTML CSS Support (>= 1.5.0), you can add the following `css.validation` settings to your `settings.json` which should clear this issue. Don't forget to reload VS Code after changing the settings though.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading the 'HTML CSS Support' extention to v1.3.3 will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, uninstall the **HTML CSS Support** then reload VS code.
You can use **IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML** if you want, it provides CSS class name completion for the HTML class attribute based on the definitions found in your workspace or external files referenced through the link element. And gives you autocompletion for CSS class definitions that can be found in your workspace (defined in CSS files or the in the file types listed in the Supported Language Modes section)

Answer (score 2):

first uninstall HTML CSS support and then reload it And i am 100% sure that it will
work actually HTML CSS support sometime checks your HTML CSS code and give error if there is false positive

Answer (score 2):

Issue with extension "HTML CSS Support"
Uninstall it or use an older verions.

Answer (score 1):

I am using SCSS as a CSS preprocessor in the Angular project with Bootstrap5. I installed the following plugin and the problem was solved.

[SCSS Everywhere](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion)

Answer (score 1):

Now, using bootstrap 5 and angular 13.2.2, the HTML CSS support extension doesn't work.

However, [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion) works for me

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Just turn off CSS validation in settings.json.

Comment: it's works for me, and don´t need uninstall the extension